# Persistence c#, Between two runs

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, voip

I have a PC client in which i want the client to remember the last username, when the client is started for the next time. How do i implement this ? I am using visual studio 2012. I am guessing it will be something to do with the registry of the local machine using the client ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could save it in the configuration file, or you could save it in the registry. You can do both... You only have to choose. I don't like very much the registry, so I normally use the configuration file.

Here there is the MSDN page that explain how to use [Settings in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Even after changing the application setting in visual studio 2012, do i have to save it in the configuration file ?

Comment: @user2054702 I don't comprehend what you asked me.

Comment: Sorry. Will try and elaborate. So i added a setting in settings.settings under properties in my solution (as suggested by the MSDN page), with name as username, type string and scope as application... and i tried to re run the client to see if it remembers the last username...but this did not work. So i asked if there is some changes that need to be made in the config file.

Comment: @user2054702 Normally the problem is that you didn't save the setting :-) `You can persist changes to user settings between application sessions by calling the Settings.Save method`

Comment: Where do i call this method, to persist the username ?

Comment: @user2054702 You modify the username and then you save it. There is an example... Look for `To Write and Persist User Settings at Run Time` in the link.

Comment: Isnt the username an application scope setting ? The link states that Application-scope settings are read only, and can only be changed at design time

Comment: @user2054702 Yes, you have to use a User Setting :-) I hadn't noticed you had used an App Sett :-)

Comment: Yes,it has to be usersetting :),my bad. When i name the setting in settings.settings how do i know the name of the variable in runtime... ?

Comment: @user2054702 If you create a setting named `LastStart`, you invoke like this: `string lastStart = Settings.Default.LastStart; Settings.Default.LastStart = DateTime.Now.ToString();Settings.Default.Save();`

Comment: Got it.In my case since i am trying to persist the last username used by the user what should be in the value field in Settings.settings ?

Comment: Could you please answer the above questions ?

Comment: Where does the code to read the setting go ? for eg :this.Username = Properties.Settings.Default.Username;

Comment: At the beginning of Main (or when you create the object with this.Username) you read the config. At the end of the program you save the last value of this.UserName

Comment: When i try to use the properties namespace by including           using XXX.Properties; in the beginning of my c# file, it says namespace not found and i am very sure that the namespace exists and there is spelling error. I tried to google a lot for a solution, but couldnt find any. Could you please share you view ?

Comment: @user2054702 If in the Solution explorer you click on the little triangle on the left of your setting file, you should see a file .Designer.cs . Open that cs and look at the namespace and at the class name

Comment: I did and i am trying to use the same namespace which is in the Designer.cs but the error still persists.